# How to get ScreenPoints from DataPoints?

Tags: c#, rendering, oxyplot

I want to get a list of screen points from the list of data points. My list of data points is filled but when I apply a transform to get screen points, the result is always 0,0 per each point. Can you tell me why?

I've tried:

```
if (!this.serie.Transform(dp).Equals(null))
```

And it causes a `NullPointerException`.

I've tried all of these tests after the `onRender` method was invoked!

Here is my code for a second test:

```
foreach (DataPoint dp in series.Points)
{
  Console.WriteLine(dp);
  Console.WriteLine(this.xAxis.Transform(dp.X, dp.Y, this.yAxis));
}
```

And the result in console:

> 41695 1.3715
>   0 0
>   41696 1.3697
>   0 0
>   41697 1.37545
>   0 0
>   41700 1.37595
>   0 0
>   41701 1.37375
>   0 0
>   41702 1.3737
>   0 0
>   41703 1.37945
>   0 0
>   41704 1.3867
>   0 0
>   41707 1.3875
>   0 0
>   41708 1.38665
>   0 0
>   41709 1.3881
>   0 0
>   41710 1.3885
>   0 0
>   41711 1.389
>   0 0

I made this after giving model to the plot view and after adding series. I add that my x axis is a `DateTime` axis and my Y axis is a linear axis.

Comment: Can you specify what is null in the example? I'm currently using `Transform` method from `Axis` class and it works with no problems.